# The effect of multiplying the weighs of a trained neural net with a scalar

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, optimization

Can somebody give us some intuition on why (sometimes) multiplying the weights of a trained neural net with a scalar $s \geq 1$ doesn't changes the accuracy, but multiplying the weights by an scalar $s < 1$ has a huge impact on the accuracy?

For example, here I show results of the scalar vs. accuracy for two tasks: MNIST classification and IMDB sentiment classification.

Both models are  a combination of CNN+FNN (from https://keras.io/examples/)

After training --> $W_{new} = scalar*W_{old}$

[image]

[image]

For example, to run MNIST experiment, run this [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/vision/ipynb/mnist_convnet.ipynb) and after training use this code:

```
original_w = model.get_weights()
for scalar in [0.001, 0.05, 0.1, .25, 0.5, .75, 0.9, 1., 5., 10., 50., 100.]:
    new_w = [scalar*w for w in original_w]
    model.set_weights(new_w)
    print("Scallar {} --> test accuracy {}".format(scalar, model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)[1]))
```

You get an output like this:

```
Scallar 0.001 --> test accuracy 0.11349999904632568
Scallar 0.05 --> test accuracy 0.11349999904632568
Scallar 0.1 --> test accuracy 0.3792000114917755
Scallar 0.25 --> test accuracy 0.9836999773979187
Scallar 0.5 --> test accuracy 0.9919999837875366
Scallar 0.75 --> test accuracy 0.9919000267982483
Scallar 0.9 --> test accuracy 0.9918000102043152
Scallar 1.0 --> test accuracy 0.9919000267982483
Scallar 5.0 --> test accuracy 0.9918000102043152
Scallar 10.0 --> test accuracy 0.9918000102043152
Scallar 50.0 --> test accuracy 0.9919000267982483
Scallar 100.0 --> test accuracy 0.9919000267982483
```

Update:

1. This is not a general case! It's an observation on two classifiers.
2. It seems to me one reason is that as usually learning algorithms encourage the network to keep the weights small. So, the trained model might be close to the smallest possible solution. Hence, multiplying with s > 1 maps it another solution with bigger weights. But, multiplying with s < 1 maps weights to a bad solution. Again, just a guess.

Comment: division by $s$ means multiplication by $1/s$, so I cannot make sense of your argument

Comment: @gunes I edited an made it clearer.

Comment: can you share a working example (your implementation with mnist for ex)

Comment: @gunes I added working example